# Multithreading file reading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a bunch of files I want to read, but each files are encrypted and compressed. I would like to speed up the process by using each core to open a file, decrypt it, and decompress it. Then pass to the next file that isn't being used.

Right now I have a for loop that reads one file at a time decrypt it, decompress and pass to the next file.

How to do it?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: You will likely find that the bottleneck is file IO rather than processing speed. AES, for example, is very fast. You could pull files into memory and the process them in parallel - using a producer/consumer pattern for example.

Comment: Change it to use a stream(), and then make it a parallelStream(). How you do that exactly depends on your code.

Comment: Well, yes I could like to do most of the work in the memory since the files are not that big like 10MB uncompressed. The encryption scheme used is blowfish

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that file IO is probably more of a bottleneck than the processing. Either way, reading files in parallel will like cause little more than hard drive thrashing - possibly an SSD or high end RAID would cope.

I would structure the program thusly:

- main `Thread` reads files and dumps them to a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)
- other threads form a `ThreadPool` and `take()` from the queue

Lets assume you have some method `void doMagicStuff(byte[] file)` that does whatever with the files.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BlockingQueue<byte[]> processingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    IntStream.range(0, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()).forEach(i -> {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            while (!done.get() || !processingQueue.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    doMagicStuff(processingQueue.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //exit
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    final Path folder = Paths.get("blah/blah");
    try (final Stream<Path> files = Files.list(folder)) {
        files.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(file -> {
                    try {
                        return Files.readAllBytes(file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).forEach(processingQueue::add);
    }

    done.set(true);
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}

public static void doMagicStuff(final byte[] data) {
    //MAGIC MAGIC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use paralelStream() e.g.

```
Map<String, String> allFiles =
   Files.walk(Paths.get("dir"))
        .parallel()
        .filter(f -> f.toString().endsWith(".gz"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.toString(), f -> decryptAndUncompress(f)));
```

Comment: You reckon this would be better than a 1producer/nconsumer?

Comment: @BoristheSpider it's a lot simpler and would use all the available CPUs. If the files are really small and you have a spinning disk, it won't help much, but if disk access is reasonable, you should get close to linear scalability with the number of cores you have.